# Why does not Qt5 addin work in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, qt5, visual-studio-addins

I have following configurations on my pc-

```
1) Visual Studio 2013 64bit      
2) Installed QT5.4.2 64bit with openGL  
3) Qt5Package addin
```

After installing the addin, it shows up on the menubar like this-

[image]

But I can not configure anything as none of the menubar options in QT5 works. I mean when I click a menu item it does not do anything.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the addin, but still having the same problem. What is the solution to this problem?

There was this error message which appeared only once: 
[image]

And in the **ActivityLog.xml** file I found this-

```
 <entry>
    <record>825</record>
    <time>2015/07/06 04:53:50.918</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{DDD4B302-4A66-4606-A193-AF0CB0D67E5C}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>826</record>
    <time>2015/07/06 04:53:50.918</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [VSPackage]</description>
    <guid>{DDD4B302-4A66-4606-A193-AF0CB0D67E5C}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>827</record>
    <time>2015/07/06 04:53:50.919</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [VSPackage]</description>
    <guid>{DDD4B302-4A66-4606-A193-AF0CB0D67E5C}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>828</record>
    <time>2015/07/06 04:53:50.919</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [VSPackage]</description>
    <guid>{DDD4B302-4A66-4606-A193-AF0CB0D67E5C}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Qt5package** addin avaiable in **Visual Studio Gallery** has dependency issues. So you need to download the full addin package from [this link](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource.exe.mirrorlist).

Answer (score 2):

The full addin package doesn't work in Visual Studio 2015 so I used Qt5Package.

I had the same problem with the Beta version of Qt5.6.0. I found a workaround - in C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf Qt 5.6.0 splits all the version-specific changes into a separate file msvc-base.conf. If you copy the contents of this file and replace the line "include(msvc- base.conf)" in mscv-desktop.conf then Qt5Package recognises the Qt 5.6.0 Beta with no problems.

Note this still needs to be fixed in Qt5Package.